# Hibernate Pagination with Sybase ASE - Heap space

Tags: hibernate, pagination, sap-ase

I'm looking to have hibernate pagination work in sybase, but since Sybase doesn't have the offset inbuilt, Hibernate tries to get all the records in the memory and scrolls to the specific record set requested and sends it to front-end.
Say for instance, if total rows are 1000 and I request for 20 records in page 2. Hibernate query fetches all records into the memory and scrolls from 21-40 and returns only those 20 rows.

The above stuff works fine for fewer set of records but when we deal with something more than 1Million records, then its emitting out the outofmemory-heap space issue.

This has a performance bottleneck associated with the memory.
I have surfed through the internet since 2-3 days, but with no luck. And I'm sure that many ppl would have come across this issue .

Could you suggest something on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your code that executes the hibernate query? Are you using the hibernate's scrollable result set feature to fetch records in batches?

Comment: @AndyDufresne Nope am not using scrollable result but the setFirstResults and setMaxResults.  i.e, query.setFirstResult(start);
query.setMaxResults(nRows);   on a different context, is there a batch processing with scrollable results?

Comment: and its just a select query from a table.

Answer (score 1):

Below is one way to read large result sets in hibernate.

```
Query query = session.createQuery(query);
query.setReadOnly(true);
// MIN_VALUE gives hint to JDBC driver to stream results
query.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
// iterate over results
while (results.next()) {
    Object row = results.get();
    // process row then release reference
    // you may need to flush() as well
}
results.close();
```

Follow [this](http://www.numerati.com/2012/06/26/reading-large-result-sets-with-hibernate-and-mysql/) link for more details.

Comment: Andy, wont this mean that the connection will be open untill we read all the rows? Say for example, if we have a million rows to read wont the connection be open untill you process the record? And on the otherhand wont this have an impact on the jvm memory for large result sets leading to outofmemory issues ?

Comment: This will keep the connection open but since it doesn't load all the records in memory it will surely not lead to OOM issues.